# How to align buttons to bottom on the page

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-4

I would like to align all button to bottom on the page:

[image]

The editor with code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-7-bootstrap-4-3pv0p?from-embed

```
<div class="container-fluid py-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
      <div class="card rounded-0">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h2>Boot Container View</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="ws-details" style="background:gray; height:100px">
                Element1
              </div>
              <div
                class="order-details"
                style="background:lightgray; height:200px"
              >
                Element 2
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div style="background:gray; height:305px">Element3</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="center-block">
                <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                  <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                      Button 1a
                    </button>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                      Button 2a
                    </button>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="center-block">
                <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                  <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                      Button 1b
                    </button>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                      Button 2b
                    </button>
                  </p>

                  <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                      Button 3b
                    </button>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="center-block">
                <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                  <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                      Button 1c
                    </button>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried with position absolute and relative with parent/child element. But still I have problem with the proper align buttons. Also - I would like to change size (width of buttons), and after change style width there is problem with center button.

Comment: Have you allready tried adding `align-bottom` to the buttons you want aligned on the bottom as explained in the bootstrap-4 documentations? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/vertical-align/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

**Changes in `app.component.html` file:**

---

On line 25 in your html file change `<div class="row">` to `<div class="row position-relative">`.

On line 27 and line 65 change `<div class="center-block">` to `<div class="center-block align-to-bottom">`

---

**Changes in `app.component.css` file:**

---

Add:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .align-to-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

---

Link to the editor: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-7-bootstrap-4-u5uet

---

To change the width of the button you could add `button.btn-info {width: 150px;}` to your css. You said then there was a problem with the center button but what problem do you mean?

Comment: Thank you - it is better. But could you please check the link with editor? Now - when I change size to small, the buttons are in element 3. Also have problem with center buttons all on the page.

Comment: @profiler I changed my answer, this should do the trick. I added a media query and changed the thing you have to edit on line 27 and 65. Also changed the css code you have to add.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect solution.

Comment: There is the solution to alignt button 1c to the right?

Answer (score 0):

use this css properties:

```
bottom:0
position:absolute
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a bootstrap for this code and thus if you need to align the buttons to the bottom, you can use a custom css. Let this css class be alignBottom.

```css
.alignBottom{
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: When I should add alignBottom? I added it in row... in center-block... in buttons. No working anywhere.